# How to send nested json as post in android

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

im using android valley library, currently im only able to post simple json, im struggling in posting nested json format like this :

```
{
"user": {
    "email": "digest@example.com",
    "password": "thedigest123"
```

it looks like i didnt know how to format the nested json for this case, could you help me?

here's my java class that i used to connect my web api

```
public void login(String email, String password) {
    String url = BASE_URL + "api/session";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonObject.put("email", email);
        jsonObject.put("password", password);

        Response.Listener<JSONObject> successListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(mApplication, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(mApplication, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, successListener, errorListener);
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mApplication, "JSON exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create dto classes for your request body:

   ```
   public class UserRequestDTO{
       private UserDto user;
       //getters, setters
   }
   public class UserDto{
       private String email;
       private String password;
   }
   ```

2. Convert it to json string using Gson lib:

   ```
   public static String stringify(Object obj) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
        return jsonString;
   }
   ```

Then convert it to StringEntity with `new StringEntity(stringify(new UserRequestDto(/*params*/), "UTF-8");`
or to JSONObject with `new JSONObject(stringify(new UserRequestDto(/*params*/));`, and use it in your request.

Comment: This would be the sensible route to go especially if there are more complex `JSONObjects`. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the overhead of Gson or creating classes (unless you intend to have more complex objects) You can simply do:

```
JSONObject userJsonObject = new JSONObject("{ \"user\": {\"email\": \"" + email + "\", \"password\": \"" + password + "\" } }");
```